# Multi-line echo area for displaying function signature with semantic-idle-summary-mode

Tags: echo-area, semantic-mode, eldoc

## Description

I've got some c-functions with long argument lists. Even if that is bad style I would like `semantic-idle-summary-mode` to help me with those bad style functions.

Pityingly it keeps the height of the echo area at one line even if the function signature does not fit into that area.

I would like the height of the echo area being adapted to the function signature.

As far as I understood the source code of `semantics-idle-summary-mode` it uses (parts of) `eldoc-mode`. Therefore I already tried to set `eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p` to t without any effect on `semantic-idle-summary-mode`.

## Version information

Emacs: `GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2016-04-25`

semantic: version 2.2 shipping with emacs

## Reproduction

- start `emacs -Q`
- Call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `semantic-mode` and switch on menu item *Development->Show Tag Summaries*
- customize `eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p` to t
- create new buffer with <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> `test.c` (there is no need for saving this buffer as file)
- paste the following c-code into that buffer:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  void fun(int a, int function, int with, int many, int arguments, int that, int dont, int fit, int on, int one, int line) {
      printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",a,function,with,many,arguments,that,dont,fit,on,one,line);
  }

  int main() {
      int a=1,function=2,with=3,many=4,arguments=5,that=6,dont=7,fit=8,on=9,one=10,line=11;
      fun(a,function,with,many,arguments,that,dont,fit,on,one,line);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- adjust frame size such that the signature of `fun` is wrapped at the window edge
- place point at the open parenthesis of the call of `fun` in `main`
- the function signature in the echo area is truncated as shown in following Figure

[image: echo area with truncated function signature]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: The full semantic tags are shown in the minibuffer if `semantic-idle-truncate-long-summaries` is customized to nil and `eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p` is customized to non-nil.

The not so short answer:

The eldoc message is generated by `semantic-idle-summary-idle-function`. This function really considers `eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p`. If `eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p` is nil it truncates the message. **But** this function additionally considers a separate option `semantic-idle-truncate-long-summaries` with very much the same functionality. The only difference is that `semantic-idle-summary-idle-function` truncates the message if `semantic-idle-truncate-long-summaries` is non-nil.

I am a bit puzzled by the existence of `semantic-idle-truncate-long-summaries`. I've got the impression that this option should be depreciated in favor of `eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p` and its default value should be changed to nil.